# Drupal issues with making pages

Tags: drupal

[image]I am new to drupal.  I have made a site and front page along with several "basic pages" from within the system itself.  What I can't see to figure out is this:

I click on a link on the home page, and it's linked to one of those "basic pages"

It just loads on a white drupal background.

What I want to do is have numerous pages with regions like I had on the front page.  How do I go about getting all this set up?

I know this probably sounds easy to most, but it escapes me at the moment.

My footer seems to stretch across all pages as well.  Though that seems to be it.

Also, I'm using drupal 7

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create new custom theme which will include in sites/all/themes/[your theme name] folder.

**Note: You need to active that new theme from appearance setting from drupal admin.**

In that folder, you will have to create different regions into .info file. Then you can please blocks on different regions as per your need using admin panel.

Now, in templates folder of your theme you need to copy page.tpl.php template and rename as page--front.tpl.php (This template will call for Home page).

You can now set your regions into these template for your home page.

After all changes, please clear cache from system admin (/admin/config/development/performance).

Comment: Will this also apply to other pages in the site?

Comment: nope..this template will only call on Home page.. If you want to show some blocks for all pages then you must insert your code on page.tpl.php template. It will call in each and every page.

Comment: I just want a content area on my home page and the same header for every other page as well.  Would this require an edit of the page.tpl.php page?  Or do I just need to set up the front to look like how I want as well?  I'm a bit confused, but i feel as though I'm way over thinking it.  Right now, the "basic page" creations do have the same footer as the home page, but the front---page file does have a footer tag, where as everything else is separated with various DIV tags.    Would i just copy the contents of my front page file to the page.tpl file?  is it really that easy?

Comment: Let me give you example.. if you want to show same header on each page including home and other basic pages then you need to put header code in page.tpl.php and as well as page--front.tpl.php file. so same header will appear on each page..

Comment: That makes sense, but if I'm linking to a node, would I have to make a node.tpl.php file as well with similar code as the page.tpl.php file?

Comment: Is there a database entry somewhere I need to alter to tell it to use these said file?

Comment: no we dont need to do entry on db. but yes. in node.tpl.php you will also put you change as per page.tpl.php.

Comment: I have created these files in the template folder, and uploaded them to the site.  I have also cleared out the cache, yet I have seen no change.  Would you have any idea what I'm missing?  Thank you again, I sincerely appreciate all your help.

Comment: Can you please check what is your current active theme is ?

Comment: I added a rudementary graphic showing what my end goal is in my original posting.  I hope that helps illustrate what I'm trying to convey.  I have checked my main theme and it is "site_theme_1" It says it's the default theme and it's a sub theme of bootstrap.

Comment: Seems my page file has a different name.  html.tpl for some reason.  I'm editing it, but I keep getting an error.  Seems some variables don't want to work.  Not sure why as they work fine on the main page.

Comment: that's strange. you can check errors by looking at recent log messages inside report section.!

Answer (score 0):

okay..just do one thing. please create three regions in .info file of theme folder.

```
regions['header'] = Header
regions['header_navigation'] = Header Navigation
regions['footer'] = Footer
```

Now, go to page.tpl.php and put below respected code in template where you want to show this feature.

### **For Header**

```
<?php print render($page['header']); ?>
```

### **For Navigation**

```
<?php print render($page['header_navigation']); ?>
```

### **For Footer**

```
<?php print render($page['footer']); ?>
```

**Note: Please make sure you have to set block from the given regions (You can check this block structure list) also make sure you are working on active theme.**

Comment: Okay, so how do I get rid of that side navigation bar on the page itself?  The thing that said add content and such.

Comment: I have also copied the page----front code over to this page.tpl file.  Seems i'm getting undefined variable errors.  Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: can you please share your template code and .info file with me?

Comment: How do I get in touch with you?

Comment: live:ff642002 is the Skype id

Comment: Awesome, I'm logged in.